# ES6 For each/map students grades

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, mapping

Need a small hint from you - newbie here.

I've got an exemplary array containing both student names and their score on the exam.

I need to do the function that checks whether student passed the exam or not(let's assume that score >= 80 is enough to pass) and in both cases it shows a proper information - "Passed" or "Didn't pass".

I need to do this using either .map structure or "for each" loop.

I'd really appreciate if you could help me :)

```
var students = [['David', 80], ['Vinoth', 77], ['Divya', 88], ['Ishitha', 95], ['Thomas', 68]];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are a lot of answers, but they have literally guessed what result you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the `Array.map` function:

```
students.map([name, score] => ({name, score, passed: score >= 80}));
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can store the result of this expression! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah well just loop over all students:

```
 for(const [name, score] of students) {
   //...
 }
```

Now you just have to log based on the score to get the information you need:

```
 if(true /*?*/) {
   console.log(name + " did pass");
 } else {
  console.log(name + " did not pass");
 }
```

*No, this doesnt work yet, I left out something for you to solve ... :)*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are going for the same (just enriched) datastructure or just output, but if you would like to build up on your existing nested array with the result:

```
students = students.map(s => { 
  return [s[0], s[1], s[1] >= 80 ? 'passed' : 'not passed'];
});
```

If you just want to output student name: passed/not passed you can instead use forEach instead

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
          var students = [['David', 80], ['Vinoth', 77], ['Divya', 88], ['Ishitha', 95], ['Thomas', 68]];
          for (var i = 0; i < students.length; ++i) {
               var item = students[i];
               if(item[1]>= 80){
                  console.log(item[0] + ": Passed.");
               }else{
                   console.log(item[0] + ": Didn't pass.");
               }

          }
     });
</script>
```

Result:

```
David: Passed.
Vinoth: Didn't pass.
Divya: Passed.
Ishitha: Passed.
Thomas: Didn't pass.
```